# Resetting Microchip MM7150 to reliable state

Tags: i2c, c, microchip, hardware, esp32

So, I recently acquired the [MM7150](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/MM7150) chip from Microchip for use in a project. It functions as a combined 9 axis motion sensor, combining a gyroscope, accelerometer and magnetometer. Specifically, I'm using the [MikroE click board](https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/click/3d-motion/3d-motion-click-manual-v100.pdf) for prototyping, which ensures I2C pullups and other requirements are met. I do not believe the circuit is at issue here.

Seemingly designed for use in phones, tablets and other similar consumer devices, it makes use of Microsoft's [HID over I2C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/hid/hid-over-i2c-guide) protocol for communication, an adaptation of USB HID for I2C.

So far, so good, however, the issue occurs when trying to reliably start the chip. The process for starting it (as best I can tell) consists of reading the HID Device Descriptor, sending the POWER ON command, resetting the device with the reset command, then receiving a report descriptor, and a feature report. At that point the chip is theoretically up and running.

This is basically exactly what the sample code (for use with the Explorer 16 PIC evaluation board) does:

```c
UINT8 VREG_init() 
{
    UINT8 ucBuf[BUF_40];                                           
    UINT8 ucSensor_num;
    UINT16 err;

    
    memset(&VREGS, 0x00, sizeof(VREGS));                            // Initialize VREG registers 

    while (POR_TIMER < I2C_POR_TIMEOUT);                            //wait here for 2 seconds elapsed since POR for MM7150 i2c engine to be up and running
    
    if (HID_I2C_completion())                                       // check initial polarity of HIDI2C_HOST_INT on RE8/INT1 if this signal is LOW (ASSERTED) to start, then issue a HID_READ command to try and clear it (MM7150 finish sensor reading that was interrupted by POR)
        return HID_INT_FAIL;

    if ( hid_i2c_descriptor_handler(GET_HID_DESC) )                 // get HID descriptor from SSC7150
    {
        VREGS.stat.stat4.SHStartStatus = VREG_SHSTART_FAIL;         // update status register (VREG 0x3F) for failure to get HID descriptor
        return HID_DESC_FAIL;
    }        
    
    hid_i2c_cmd_process(ucBuf, POWER_ON, ARB_ID);                   // Issue HID Power ON command to SSC7150 (NOTE: 'ucBuf' and 'ARB_ID' are don't cares for POWER_ON command)
    
    VREGS.SHC.reset = VREG_RESET_INIT;                              //set the SHC reset bit to indicate this operation has not yet completed successfully
    if ( hid_i2c_cmd_process (ucBuf, RESET_DEV_CMD, ARB_ID) )       // Issue HID Reset command  (NOTE: 'ucBuf' and 'ARB_ID' are don't cares for RESET_REG command)
    {
        VREGS.stat.stat4.SHStartStatus = VREG_SHSTART_FAIL;         // If HID Reset fails, update status register (VREG 0x3F)
        return RESET_FAIL;
    }    
    
    if ( (err = hid_i2c_descriptor_handler(GET_RPT_DESC)) != SUCCESS ) // Get HID Report descriptor from SSC7150 
    {
        VREGS.stat.stat4.SHStartStatus = VREG_SHSTART_FAIL;         // HID report descriptor error, update status register (VREG 0x3F)
        return (err);
    }   
    
    for (ucSensor_num = 0; ucSensor_num <= NUM_SENS; ucSensor_num++) //go through the sensor list but only GetFeatureReport for valid ids   
    {
        if (SENSOR[ucSensor_num].id != 0xFF && SENSOR[ucSensor_num].id != 0)
        {
            hid_i2c_cmd_process(ucBuf, HID_GET_RPT_FEAT, SENSOR[ucSensor_num].id);  // Get feature report for all valid sensors and update VREGS register
        }
    }

    
    VREGS.stat.stat4.SHStartStatus = VREG_SHSTART_SUCCESS;          // HID startup successful, update status register (VREG 0x3F) 

    VREGS.SHC.SHwake = TRUE;                                        // HID device is now awake and ready for operation
    VREGS.SHC.SHstart = TRUE;

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

However, attempting to replicate this on the ESP32 fails the majority of the time, as the PIC example code seems to rely on a power on reset of the MM7150, although this is also something I can't reliably recreate.

Occasionally, after a few resets, I can read the correct HID descriptor from the MM7150, but then it'll fail again.

###### Successful Read

[image: Succesful Read]

##### Failed Read

[image: Failed Read]

I can't tell whether the purple parts of the second image (data write 0x80), are due to the ESP32 causing an issue, or just Sigrok decoding things strangely.

Has anyone worked with this sensor before? Any tips would be appreciated. At this point I feel it's something on the ESP32's side, causing it to send these spurious data writes, but that doesn't really explain why sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't, and I'm still not certain how to reliably reset the sensor. There is a HOST_TO_SH_RESET pin, but it's purpose is unclear, and pulling it to ground doesn't seem to do anything.

[image: Reset pin description]

Comment: Ok, I managed to solve it. It turns out that the i2c command queues on the ESP32 FreeRTOS SDK are supposed to be disposed of after sending one message. I was getting spurious results due to re-use of the queue. Still unsure of what the reset pin does, but the reset procedure over I2C works correctly.